# Using C++ for performance intense applications?

Tags: c++, c, performance

Is it wise to use c++ for intense calculations, like millions of loops, millions of items in arrays etc?

To be more specific, is it a good idea to use **only** C functions on a C++ program for performance reasons?

Will this application perform slower than the same one written in C?

As you know, it is more convenience to write C++ (you don't have to define everything, more libraries supported, if needed you can use slow but work saving functions).

This site: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/c.php makes be believe C is faster.

Comment: "is it a good idea to use only C functions on a C++ program for performance reasons?" No, it's a bad idea. Why? Because you'll probably see very little, if any, difference in performance. Unless you write poor C or C++. But then that's your fault, not the language's.

Comment: There's no better performance of [tag:c] code vs [tag:c++] code. Bad performance comes from bad written code, no matter which language.

Comment: I am sorry, but in some scenarios there is REAL difference, especially if the function is used millions of time.

Comment: like for example 2-5 times when using c functions instead of c++ in a 1 billion times loop.

Comment: C and C++, written the same way, with rtti and exceptions turned off, should compile to identical machine code. The example you linked is comparing code written differently.

Comment: @Blazer: I doubt it. Unless the C and C++ compilers are significantly different, I don't think well written C and C++ code would vary that much.

Comment: You can also have calculations in the C-part and higher level control in C++.  They can be linked.

Comment: using Microsoft visual studio 2012, the same c++ program performs about 3 times faster. because: a) i used arrays and no vectors (yes, i never used push_back) b) i made the string to int conversion with custom functions and not ultra slow c++ ones

Comment: @Blazer: Your choice of language didn't magically make that faster. It was how you programmed it that made it faster. Choose whatever language you want, and then program it well. How you program it will have *far* more impact than the actual language you choose.

Comment: For performance, write everything in assembly, dropping down to C only when when you find a significant readability problem.

Comment: @Blazer Using `std::vector` in c++ **isn't** identical to using arrays in c!

Comment: yes, but for my case it was exactly the same. Assembly, is very time consuming and not in my choice list, because of that.

Comment: You're stuck believing a fallacy but I don't think anyone here will be able to convince you of such...

Comment: @Mehrdad About C# vs C++ performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759529/how-to-efficiently-manage-memory-time-in-c . Simply adding manual deleting (instead of Java's automatic) has slown down the program almost 4 times. Still so hard to believe, that simply switching from manual dynamic memory allocation to automatic mamory management can speed up the program so much?

Comment: @Spook: I've seen tons of anecdotes before, but *zero* examples. Where's the code that reproduces this supposed performance increase? Until you can show me code that demonstrates this, I call BS on it.

Comment: @Mehrdad Here you go. Simple program *only for demonstration of the problem*: http://pastebin.com/tr4HtPKi - C# version, 15ms. http://pastebin.com/2rwc2zgB - C++ version, 107ms - VS 2013, both Release w/o IDE.

Comment: @Mehrdad Remember, that this is only an example program: I might have reused the array in both cases, what would reduce memory operations and thus increase performance. The point is, that in real world this is not always possible and in my particular case actually it wasn't.

Comment: @Spook so i was curious and benched your program on my machine. If you compile it as it is, the c++ version is indeed much slower, but that’s because you leak memory. When you insert a `delete` in the outer loop, both versions take the same time.

Comment: @Blazer for your example of calling functions thousands or millions of times, have you tried loop unrolling to see how faster it is. Most C and C++ compilers will perform this optimization on request, so it doesn't matter which language you use.

Comment: @Spook: Indeed, see Darklighter's comment. You're leaking memory, that slows it down considerably.

Comment: @Spook: Your array in C# has only 1k elements, but in C++ 10k. THATS UNFAIR!

Comment: That's my mistake indeed. It seems, that I will have to dig in my archives after all...

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ for high performance code is not a bad idea. Your primary approach to performance should be choosing effective data structures and algorithms, backed by a good performance profiling tool to find unexpected hot spots and analyze the behavior of your code.

Comment: +1 for the mentioning of profiling tools.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question have different answers. Consider the following cases.
-Loops doesn't depend on the programming language that much, it is more dependent on CPU. CPU's have loop prediction to make Loop execute faster.

-If your using classes, yes it will be slower due to virtual dispatch. In Software Engineering standpoint though, Computers are getting faster, we programmers are not so abstractions is our only tool to maximize coding productivity.

Comment: Using classes doesn't inherently require virtual dispatch. Only virtual functions require that.

Comment: Classes don't always use virtual dispatch. And if they do, then you have to do the same thing in C anyway, more or less (unless you decide to architecture the program differently, in which case, why not architecture it differently in C++ too?).

Answer (score 0):

In general, a C++ program written for performance will be at least as good as a similar C program.  It may be better as templates facilitate code reuse with more compile time optimisations (inlining, elimination of dead code etc.) than C equivalents like `qsort` and `bsearch`.  C++ libraries offer things like `std::unordered_map` and `std::sort` that make it easy for C++ programs to utilise efficient data structures and algorithms, while C programs may stick to arrays and brute force algorithms more often.

If the C++ program uses libraries that have higher overheads, or is structured differently (e.g. using OO and lots of virtual dispatch), then it's possible the C++ program may end up slower.  Historically, lots of people reported C++ I/O streams being significantly slower than C-library alternatives, but they do a bit more in terms of honour locales and maintaining some state, and modern implementations may be faster for some operations.

For operations on primitive types, looping, function calls etc. not involving complex libraries, there'll generally be no performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

C is indeed great for highly demanding computations. However, I am not sure you will see much difference compared to C++. If you have performance issues, you should mainly focus on finding fast algorithms instead of trying low-level [**program optimizations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#.22Levels.22_of_optimization). Compilers can do a much better job than you. In particular, for this [**SPOJ problem**](http://www.spoj.com/problems/INVCNT/), the naïve algorithm times out even for well-written, highly optimized code. The "clever" algorithm (even poorly written) is at least 10 times faster.

Also, you may try to see if you can perform the computations in parallel. Then, you may try using [**GPGPU**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) with:

1. [**CUDA**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)
2. [**OpenCL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)
3. [**OpenGL compute shaders**](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader)

In these cases, C and C++ are mandatory.