# How to efficiently manage memory/time in C++?

Tags: java, c++, memory, garbage-collection

The case:

I wrote a minimax algorithm in Java, then I ported the code in C++, mantaining the same classes and methods. Then I valgrinded the C++ code until all memory leaks were fixed by putting `delete` functions in destructors (when possible). When all leaks were fixed, I tested the algorithm on a tic-tac-toe game, which code was then ported identically in C++. I was sure that the C++ version would have been more performant, however I was surprised seeing that 100 (not random) instances of the game were solved in 125 seconds by C++ version while the Java version solved them in 30 seconds!
Then, using System Monitor I checked the memory usage of the two programs: the Java code memory usage at the end of the test increased roughly 20% while with the C++ version the memory only increased of 5%.

Then, at my eyes, it's clear that this `delete` policy is memory saving but kills time performance, which is not what I want, at least in this case. Is there another deletion policy to better design softwares which requires small runtime but allow high memory usage?

Comment: Optimization is a tricky matter, ¿are you sure that delete is giving you all that trouble?  Do you have any way to profile your C++ execution time in order to find time spent on delete calls?

Comment: Yes, I could try to measure time consumed by deletion cycles. I'll do it and I'll update you.

Comment: Posting your code would help a lot in analyzing the problem.

Comment: @bancsy Yes, I know but the code consists of thousands lines both for Java and C++.

Comment: Java and C++ are different languages. Imagine you tried speaking Portuguese by doing a word-by-word literal translation from your native Bulgarian; the result wouldn't be pretty, no matter how pretty some native Portuguese speakers are.

Comment: And I really can't slap my head hard enough at the "programming style" of "adding `delete` until valgrind stops complaining". Don't program by guessing! Learn the language, and program constructively by understanding what you *can* do. Play by the rules; don't just shake and hope for the best.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason that a tic-tac-toe program would need dynamic allocation. Minmax **descriptions** talk about a move tree, but in practice you generate moves on the fly in recursive calls.

Comment: @PeteBecker I give you a good reason: test correctness and performance of my basic minimax algorithm on a small, easy multiplayer game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

malloc and delete have to do more work as

- memory is not allocates in a multi-threaded way
- memory is not allocated continuously in memory, but for regions of free memory.
- `delete` is performed in the current thread.
- for 64-bit applications you may find the memory alignment is 16 bytes instead of 8 bytes, resulting in more padding per allocation.

Possible solutions in C++

- don't use the heap so much, allocating on the stack is much faster than Java's or C++'s heap, and it is multi-threaded.
- allocate blocks of objects at once if possible e.g. an array of objects is one allocation in C++ instead of N+1 in Java.
- use a multi-threaded allocator.  C++ supports multiple allocators.
- use an arena allocation pattern.  If you have a large data structure with lots of nodes, you can allocate blocks of N node at a time and when you free such nodes, build a linked list of free node.  You need to do this with the nodes themselves.  In this approach the whole data structure/arena is deallocated at once.

In short, if you do a literal translation of Java code to C++, it may well be slower as this doesn't take advantage of all the optimisations C++ allows but Java doesn't.

BTW Java 6+ uses 32-bit references for up to 32 GB of memory. If you build a 64-bit C++ application, see if using 32-bit pointers/references/indexes is an option for you.

Comment: I have to build a big tree. Following your advice, would be a good idea to design a NodeFactory which allocates, for instance 1000 nodes at once and gives reference "on-demand" to the minimax algorithm?

Comment: @HAL9000 Provided you never need to recycle nodes or you have a simple recycling strategy e.g. the tree is only added to and freed all at once, this should be much faster. If you have heavy mix of `delete` and `malloc` you might not have a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are constantly building a tree (with a lot of small
dynamically allocated nodes) and tearing it down, you are in the
most favorable case for garbage collection.  You might want to
use the Boehm collector with C++.  (IIRC, Boehm's benchmark,
designed to show that garbage collection can be faster than
manual allocation, does something very similar to this: builds
large trees, then tears them down.)

Alternatively, you could look into some sort of memory pool.
This is not a beginner's technique in C++, but it isn't that
difficult either.  Or, rather than deleting the nodes, you put
them onto a free list, to recycle later.  (When allocating, you
look first to the free list, and only call `new` if it is
empty.)  Or combine the two.